# SSIS containers executing in parallel share variables

Tags: ssis

I have an SSIS package where in there are 21 sequence containers that run in parallel. I need to store the start time of each of the container execution so that I can log the time of execution at the end of each container execution.

Also, I require copies of another variable in each container. I do not want to create 42 variables. Is there a way I can create one variable such that each container has its own copy during run time? The variable need not exist after execution of the container.

Answer (score 0):

I started to say that you have several options, but if you are running these all in parallel, then I think you don't:   Your best option is to store the start times in a table.

That or create 42 variables.

Comment: Or create the variable scoped to a new sequence container. Copy paste (Control Flow now has `SEQ Variable Container` and `SEQ Variable Container 1`) Move the first parallel sequence container inside #1. Lather, rinse, repeat for the 20 remaining. Now each container has access to the same named variables but their own copy of it.

Comment: Let me see if I understand:  If a sequence container has a variable scoped to it, any containers directly inside it automatically have access to a variable with the same name, but scoped specifically to them?

Comment: [Correct](http://i.stack.imgur.com/d5fMI.png) The default behavior 2012 forward is that variables are always created at the Control Flow/global level. Prior to this, wherever your mouse had last clicked is where the variable was scoped. To manually move them, the second/highlighted icon is Move Variable. 2005/2008 users needed to install [Bids Helper](http://bidshelper.codeplex.com) to get that functionality (fifth icon)

Comment: @billinkc I tested and had a problem:  Although the child containers did have access to the parent containers variable, they seemed to share the same memory space.  When I set the variable to 1 in the first child, and to 2 in the second child, and then used messageboxes in both children to see the value, and ran them in parallel, both messageboxes showed the variable had a value of 2.  So it looks like they both get access to the same variable, and they don't both get their own independent copy of that variable.   So I don't think this solution will work for the OP's requirement.